# Python: How to do several float formattings with 1 lambda function

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

I have a numpy array 
    [2.15295647e+01, 8.12531501e+00, 3.97113829e+00, 1.00777250e+01]
and would like to format it so that it looks like this
    [21.53, 08.13, 03.97, 10.08]

```
float_formatter = lambda x: "%.2f" % x
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':float_formatter})
```

How can I adjust this to contain 2 float manipulations?

I need something like %02d %.2f % (x,y) but don't know how to change the lambda function to do this.

Comment: The second half of the question ("2 float manipulations") doesn't seem to be related to the first part in any way. What does the input for the second part look like? What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with two floats in your lambda, you need two input arguments like this:

```
float_formatter = lambda x, y: "%.2f %.2f" % (x, y)
```

You can define multiple inputs to lambda expressions, not just a single and the name is arbitrary. Here's the same thing with different argument names.

```
float_formatter = lambda float_one, float_two: "%.2f %.2f" % (float_one, float_two)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you just want your array values to be padded with two leading zeros and printed to two decimal places. All you need to do is modify the formatting string:

```
In [1]: "%05.2f" %np.pi
Out[1]: '03.14'
```

To break this down, the `5` means that the total length of the formatted string is 5 characters (including the decimal point), the `0` means that you want to pad with leading zeros, and the `.2` means that you want two figures after the decimal point.

So if you wanted, say, 3 leading zeros and 4 decimal places you would do:

```
In [2]: "%08.4f" %np.pi
Out[2]: '003.1416
```

If you just wanted to pad with leading spaces rather than zeros, you can omit the `0` in front of the total length:

```
In [3]: "%8.4f" %np.pi
Out[3]: '  3.1416'
```

There are other options that you can read about in the [table of conversion flags here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

To set this as your new formatter, you would just do:

```
In [4]: float_formatter = lambda x: "%05.2f" %x

In [5]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':float_formatter})
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the values in the list you could use a list comprehension. Python 3 example below.

```
import numpy as np

precision = 2
formatter = "{0:."+str(precision)+"f}"

a = np.array([2.15295647e+01, 8.12531501e+00, 3.97113829e+00, 1.00777250e+01])
aFormat = np.array([float(formatter.format(i)) for i in a])
print(a, aFormat)
```

I first tried epileptic fish's option, but the printer function doesn't give you an array. It just gives you a float. So if you really want to change the print option for a 2d numpy matrix you will have to define your own function with an external counter on what to format which value with. The example below shows this with a class, because you don't want the external counter to be a global.

```
import numpy

class npPrint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.precision = 2
    # end Constructor

    def printer(self, x):
        self.precision = 2
        if self.counter == 0:
            formatter = "{0:."+str(self.precision)+"f}"
            self.counter += 1
        else:
            formatter = "{0:0"+str(self.precision)+"d}"
            x = int(round(x))
            self.counter = 0

        return formatter.format(x)
    # end printer

formatter = npPrint()
a = numpy.array([[2.15295647e+01, 8.12531501e+00], [3.97113829e+00, 1.00777250e+01]])

numpy.set_printoptions(formatter={"float_kind": lambda x, f=formatter: f.printer(x)})

print(a)
```

You have to have a counter, because you don't know if you are handed the x value or the y value. You just receive a float. This is really ugly. If I were you I would handle the printing myself and break apart the 2d matrix.